# FileNotFound exception

Tags: java, servlets, file-io, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a file in a servlet. I am using eclipse IDE.

I get a FileNotFoundException if I provide relative file name.

```
List<String> ls=new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Input.txt"));
while(input.hasNextLine()) {
   ls.add(input.nextLine());
}
```

The same code works if I put the absolute path like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("F:/Spring and other stuff/AjaxDemo/src/com/pdd/ajax/Input.txt"));
```

The Java file and text file are there in the same folder.

Does it searches text file in some other folder ?

Comment: Place your file outside `src` folder..

Comment: If the file ends up on the class path, read it as a resource. If it's a file that needs to change (like a config file) then it's better to place it outside the app context and provide the directory in which it can be found as an initialization parameter.

Comment: System.out.println(new File("Input.txt").getAbsolutePath()); Print this and see, where it is searching and place your file there!!!

Comment: How do i make it search in the directory of my project?

Comment: I placed the file outside src folder but it didnt help.

Comment: @DaveNewton Its not a config file .It has strings that i want to load in my ArrayList

Comment: Use getResourceAsStream, or whatever it's called. Don't open it using normal file IO.

Comment: By mentioning the project directory! Full Path!

Comment: I don't understand why people are answering the question as they are: Java has a known mechanism for loading files from the class path, and it is what should be used in a servlet-or an absolute path should be provided (likely *outside* the app's deployment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Setting the Working Directory

One option you have when working inside of Eclipse is to [set the working directory](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-executionArgs.htm?cp=1_3_6_6) in your launch configuration. To do this:

1. Navigate to `Run` | `Run Configurations`...
2. Select your configuration in the left hand pane
3. Select the `Arguments` tab
4. Navigate to the `Working directory` section
5. Select `Other`
6. Enter in your desired base directory

You can validate this in a test by printing:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

This has the benefit of not changing your code for production vs. test.

### Recommendation

However, the best approach is to always be explicit about the working directory by way of configuration. This puts the working directory under the direct control of your application and away from tools and servlet containers such as Eclipse and Tomcat. To do this, you would use the following [`File` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
new File(parent, file)
```

Answer (score 0):

**-** If you are using IDE like `Eclipse`, place the file in the `Application's Project Folder`.

**-** You can also place it in the `src` folder.